# Sql select clause with three table

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a sql query to show student list for each course.
The diagram below show the database relationship.

The SQL query I have written is:

```
select * from Courses 
inner join Enrollments on Enrollments.CourseId = Courses.CourseId
inner join Student on Enrollments.StudentId = StudentId
where Courses.CourseId = 1
```

[image]

The issue is that i am getting returned alot more data than I expected as only one student is registered for the course but i get ten entries. I am not sure if i have done somethings fundamental wrong or is my query the issue.

This is the data
[image]

This is the result
[image]

I expected only two rows to be returned.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some sample data, the result you get for it, and the result you'd expect to get?

Comment: *only one student is registered for the course* In the table there are 2 students for CourseId = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary key of table `Student` is `Id`, not `StudentId`.
So the correct query is:

```sql
select * from Courses 
inner join Enrollments on Enrollments.CourseId = Courses.CourseId
inner join Student on Enrollments.StudentId = Student.Id
where Courses.CourseId = 1
```

Comment: I dont want to filter by studentId. I want to get all the students that are registered for a course, Thats why i have where course.courseid = 1

Comment: I see, I think it's in this line: `inner join Student on Enrollments.StudentId = StudentId`, which should be `inner join Student on Enrollments.StudentId = Student.Id`

Comment: So why do you mark the other answer as the correct one? That does not give you the solution.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen because the other answer provided the solution before you did.

Comment: Yes it did. You initially posted a wrong answer and only after you saw the code in my answer you edited and posted the same code.

Comment: @forpas: edit history tells another story. I think I submitted my first comment on this answer with the correct answer at the exact same time you corrected your initial answer. I only saw your modified answer after the page refresh...

Comment: You posted your comment at 21:46:30 after the OP edited my typo from Studentid to Id at 21:45:51. Check the timestamps.

Comment: @forpas: that was the *suggested* edit on your answer, which was not visible for me until you approved it after I submitted my comment. Hence the confusion. Please do not accuse me of copying someone else's answer. I don't need that.

Answer (score 2):

Every column in your query must be qualified with the table's name.
You did not qualify the column `StudentId` in this join:

```
inner join Student on Enrollments.StudentId = StudentId
```

If you did you would find the error which is that there is no column `StudentId` in the table `Student` and you should use the column `Id`:

```
select * from Courses 
inner join Enrollments on Enrollments.CourseId = Courses.CourseId
inner join Student on Enrollments.StudentId = Student.Id
where Courses.CourseId = 1
```

or better with aliases for the tables:

```
select * 
from Courses as c
inner join Enrollments as e on e.CourseId = c.CourseId
inner join Student as s on e.StudentId = s.Id
where c.CourseId = 1
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Qualifying tables is not a requirement in SQL. It is only needed in cases of ambiguity.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen can you write the above query without qualifying the columns with the tables names/alaises?

Comment: Yes, column Id on table Student does not need to be qualified, because it's unique for all three tables.

Comment: Then post the query without any qualifiers. Can you do it?